# Prevent React-Select from ever being blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

We are using React-Select within our forms.
We would like to have a select dropdown that can never be blank (similar to include_blank: false in Rail's SimpleForm).

```
<Select
  simpleValue={true}
  id={input.name} {...input} {...inputHtml}
  className={inputClass}
  name="form-field-name"
  value={value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  options={selectOptions}
  multi={this.props.multi}
  clearable={false}
/>
```

I am passing in options (which are appearing, and setting clearable to false, but the select field is still able to be blank. Is there a way to prevent the blank from even being an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore setting a `selectedOption` when you don't get an option to the `onChange` callback it will work as expected:

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const options = [
      { value: "one", label: "One" },
      { value: "two", label: "Two" }
    ];
    this.state = {
      options,
      selectedOption: options[0]
    };
  }

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    if (selectedOption) {
      this.setState({ selectedOption });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { options, selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
        clearable={false}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It was the if statement in the handle change that did it. Thanks!